# How to get the amount with lots of conditions

Tags: excel

What codes should i used in excel for the below data?

```
account ccy cash balance    sequence

C   gbp  30,000.00  1

H   eur  25,000.00  1

H   eur  25,000.00  2

H   eur  25,000.00  3

C   usd  15,000.00  1

C   usd  15,000.00  2

C   usd  15,000.00  3

C   usd  15,000.00  4
```

What i wanted here is to get the cash balance of the particular account and currency. However, the cash balance should be the one with the last sequence.you may notice that the cash balance are repeating but i still need to get the last sequence because it is the last balance of that particular account-currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem need to be sliced into several problems:

1. In order to find the **Last Sequence**, you need to be able to sort them with a **GroupBy**. You need to build that.
2. In order to find the **Latest Balance**, you need to have a **SearchKey**. You need to build that.
3. To Find the Last Sequence, you need to use the `MAX()`, but you need to enter a array-range instead (see the `{}` in the formula).
4. To finally search for the Last Balance, you use the `VLookUp()` with the SearchKey.

I created this example file here: http://www.filedropper.com/example01

[image]

Comment: is it still possible to put one formula on a given cell and avoid including additional columns? perhaps like using sumifs and max function

Comment: If you don't like to see those columns, hide them :)  You need the additional columns to perform the array-range Max() and the VLookUp(). So your best option is to hide the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I would just filter but if that does not suit a PivotTable might (`account` for COLUMNS, `ccy` over `sequence` for ROWS, `sum of cash balance` for VALUES, in tabular form with Repeat item labels checked). Assuming the PT top left is in F1, then maybe in K3 and copied down to suit:

```
  =IF(MAX(IF(F:F=F3,G:G))=G3,"*","")
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter to flag the relevant rows. Would though *not* flag an account in the same currency as another which has a greater sequence number for a different account.